# How to group DataTable and sort each group by a field?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `DataTable` that looks like below;

```
| ItemName | ItemNo |   ItemValue
     A         2            3,1
     B         1            2,2
     C         3            1,5
     A         2            2,0
     B         1            1,4
     A         2            2,7
     C         3            1,3
     C         3            2,1
     B         1            1,9
```

I want to group above DataTable by `ItemName` and sort these groups by `ItemNo` first, then sort the each sorted group inside by `ItemValue`.

How can I achieve this?

Note: after sorting, I want my table like below;

```
| ItemName | ItemNo |   ItemValue
     B         1            1,4
     B         1            1,9
     B         1            2,2
     A         2            2,0
     A         2            2,7
     A         2            3,1
     C         3            1,3
     C         3            1,5
     C         3            2,1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
table = table.AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("ItemName"))
             .OrderBy(g => g.Max(r => r.Field<int>("ItemNo")))
             .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(r => r.Field<double>("ItemValue")))
             .CopyToDataTable();
```

> I want to group above DataTable by ItemName and sort these groups by
>   ItemNo first, then sort the each sorted group inside by ItemValue.

But `ItemNo` is not part of the goup-key, so how do you want to sort the groups by ItemNo if the values are different in each group(as opposed to your sample data)? By max/min/avg value? I have used `Max` to demonstrate one approach.

**Edit**  So actually both columns belong to the same key, then i would use an anonymous type as grouping key that contains both columns, then it's even clearer:

```
table = table.AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(r => new
             { 
                 ItemName = r.Field<string>("ItemName"),
                 ItemNo   = r.Field<int>("ItemNo") 
             })
             .OrderBy(g => g.Key.ItemNo)
             .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(r => r.Field<double>("ItemValue")))
             .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Each group has unique number. So A group's ItemNo = 2, B group's ItemNo = 1, C group's ItemNo = 3. After grouping, tables must be sorted by these ItemNo's

Comment: @MehmetInce: So actually both columns belong to the same key, then i would use an anonymous type as grouping key with both columns, then it's even clearer: `.GroupBy(r => new{ 
                 ItemName=r.Field<string>("ItemName"),
                 ItemNo=r.Field<int>("ItemNo") 
             }).OrderBy(g => g.Key.ItemNo)`. Edited my answer.

Comment: It gives syntactic error in visual studio. Can you write the latest solution in your answer above? so thanks for your replies also :)

Comment: @MehmetInce: I have already edited my answer to include this approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a `SortYourDataTable` method like;

```
public static DataTable SortYourDataTable(DataTable dt, string column)
{
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = column;
    dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
    return dt;
}
```

Then call it;

```
SortYourDataTable(SortYourDataTable(SortYourDataTable(dt, "ItemNo"), "ItemName"), "ItemValue");
```